# In ActionScript 3.0, when using Ookla's Speedtest in an SWFLoader, how do you allow it to load and run more than once?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader, speed-test

Got another weird/specific question for y'all:  I'm able to do with this with other .swfs just fine, but Ookla's Speedtest is something of a problem.  Basically we have a part of our website that runs Speedtest to determine somebody's bandwidth and use its results in some if statements.  But when the person tries to change panels and come back in, Speedtest just sort of disappears.  It's supposed to go back to the beginning and start again, but it's like it just keeps running and turns invisible.

When I tried loading another .swf in the SWFLoader, I could get it to reset just fine without disappearing.  There's something specifically about Ookla's Speedtest that's causing a problem.  If I do nothing to reset the Speedtest .swf when the user starts moving around panels, it won't disappear at least.  Putting in code to make it reset is a completely different story though.

What's the trick for this program?  Did Ookla design the .swf specifically so it wouldn't work like that or something?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a paid version of the swf? Have you contacted the company to see if they support this kind of usage, has this been tested outside of a local dev build on a server you may have security issues when you try to bring this to production if you're loading a swf from another domain that doesn't have a crossdomain policy file in place.  Most likely due to the specific nature of this question it'll be unlikely to get an answer from the stackoverflow community, my guess is you'll have to work with Ookla directly if you get an answer please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently Ookla has designed the .swf against being used like that, which is probably costing them customers.

Comment: Probably not, as there are no alternatives to the Ookla Speedtest